# simple client server chat application not working

Tags: java, swing, networking, serversocket

I am trying to a simple client server chat application using Stream sockets and Swing. But it is not working as it should. Apparently the server just waits for connection and does not proceed.

I have three java files, Server.java , Client.java and ChatApp.java

**Server.java**

```
    package com.htpj.networkingChatApp;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.EOFException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

    public class Server extends JFrame {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JTextArea displayArea;
        private JTextField messageEnterField;
        private ServerSocket server;
        private Socket connectionSocket;
        private ObjectInputStream input;
        private ObjectOutputStream output;
        private int counter = 1;

        protected void serverGui() {
            messageEnterField = new JTextField();
            setMessageEnterFieldEditable(false);

            messageEnterField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    sendDataToClient(e.getActionCommand());
                }
            });

            add(messageEnterField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            displayArea = new JTextArea();
            add(new JScrollPane(displayArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            displayArea.setEditable(false); // display area is never editable

            setSize(500, 500);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setTitle("Chat Server");
            setVisible(true);

        }

        protected void runServer() {

            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(2000, 100);

                while (true) {
                    try {
                        waitForConnection(); // wait for a connection
                        getStreams(); // get input and output streams
                        processConnection(); // process connections

                    } catch (EOFException e) {
                        displayMessage("\n server terminated the connection");
                    } finally {
                        closeConnection();
                        ++counter;
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } // ENDOF method runServer

        private void waitForConnection() {

            try {

                displayMessage("Waiting for Connection\n");
                connectionSocket = server.accept();
                displayMessage("Connection" + counter + "received from: " + connectionSocket.getInetAddress() + "port: "
                        + connectionSocket.getPort());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } // ENDOF method waitForConnection

        private void getStreams() throws IOException {

            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            output.flush(); // flush output buffer to send header information

            input = new ObjectInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());

            displayMessage("\n Got I/O Streams \n");
        } // ENDOF getStreams method

        private void processConnection() throws IOException {

            String message = null;
            sendDataToClient("Connection Successful \n");

            setMessageEnterFieldEditable(true); // enable server to type message

            do {
                try {

                    message = (String) input.readObject();
                    displayMessage("\n" + message);

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } while (!message.equals("CLIENT >> TERMINATE"));
        } // ENDOF processConnection method

        private void closeConnection() {

            displayMessage("\n closing connection \n");

            setMessageEnterFieldEditable(false);

            try {
                output.close();
                input.close();
                connectionSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } // ENDOF closeConnection method

        private void sendDataToClient(String messageFromServer) {

            try {
                output.writeObject("SERVER>> " + messageFromServer);
                output.flush(); // flush output to client
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } // ENDOF sendDataToClient method

        private void displayMessage(String showMessage) {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    displayArea.append(showMessage);
                }
            });
        } // ENDOF method displayMessage

        private void setMessageEnterFieldEditable(final boolean isEditable) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageEnterField.setEditable(isEditable);
                }
            });
        }

    } // ENDOF class server
```

**Client.java**

```
package com.htpj.networkingChatApp;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Client extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField messageEnterField;
    private JTextArea displayArea;

    private String chatHost;
    private Socket clientSocket;

    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;

    private String message = "";

    public Client(String host) {
        this.chatHost = host;
    }

    protected void clientGui() {
        messageEnterField = new JTextField();

        setMessageEnterFieldEditable(false);

        messageEnterField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                sendDataToServer(e.getActionCommand());
            }
        });

        add(messageEnterField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        displayArea = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane(displayArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        displayArea.setEditable(false);

        setTitle("Chat Client");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    } // END OF clientGui method

    // connect to the server and process message from server
    protected void runClient() throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        // connect to server, get Streams, process connection
        try {
            connectToServer();
            getStreams();
            processConnection();

        } catch (EOFException e) {
            displayMessage("\n client closed the connection");
        } finally {
            closeConnection();
        }
    }

    private void connectToServer() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        displayMessage("Attempting Connection to Server: \n");

        clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(chatHost), 2000);
        displayMessage(
                "Connected to: " + clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName() + "on Port : " + clientSocket.getPort());

    } // END OF method connectToServer

    private void getStreams() throws IOException {

        output = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();

        input = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        displayMessage("\n  Got I/O stream \n ");

    } // END OF getStreams method

    private void processConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

        displayMessage("\n connected to server\n");

        setMessageEnterFieldEditable(true);

        do {

            message = (String) input.readObject();
            displayMessage("\n" + message);

        } while (!message.equals("SERVER>> TERMINATE"));

    } // end of processConnection method

    private void closeConnection() throws IOException {
        displayMessage("\n closing connection ");
        input.close();
        output.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        setMessageEnterFieldEditable(false);

    } // end of closeConnection method

    private void displayMessage(final String messageToShow) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                displayArea.append(messageToShow);
            }
        });

    } // end of displayMessage method

    private void sendDataToServer(String messageToServer) {
        try {
            output.writeObject(messageToServer);
            output.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } // end of sendDataToServer method

    private void setMessageEnterFieldEditable(final boolean isEditable) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                messageEnterField.setEditable(isEditable);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**ChatApp.java**

```
package com.htpj.networkingChatApp;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ChatApp{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Server chatServer = new Server();
        Client chatClient = new Client("127.0.0.1");

        chatServer.serverGui();
        chatClient.clientGui();

         chatServer.runServer();
        try {
            chatClient.runClient();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So you `ChatApp` creates a `Server` and a `Client` and then calls `runServer`, which enters an infinite loop, so `client.runClient` can never be reached. You're also running the risk of violating the thread rules of Swing.  You should never run blocking or long running in within the Event Dispatching Thread and you should never update the UI from outside of the context of the EDT either

Comment: Consider having a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a possible solution. Generally speaking, you will need to impove you understand of concurrency in Java and Swing